# Can I avoid if-elsif-else in this ruby function?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, control-flow

I have three values (foo,bar,bad) and based on which one I pass into a function I want to use the other two.

For example calling `self.method(foo)` would result in something like this with `foo` being undefined.

```
def method
  self.foo = 180 - self.bar - self.bad
end
```

I can do it with a simple if-elsif-else setup, but is there a better (more idiomatic) way?

**Update for clarity:**

Here's what one suggestion might look like in production:

```
def solve_angles(missing)
  angles = 180 - [ A, B, C ].reject { |e| e == missing }.inject(:+)
end
```

called via `@triangle.solve_angles(self.C)` or even '@triangle.solve_angles("C") would be possible.

Comment: It totally depends; is the decision value-based, or literally dependent on the symbol?

Comment: It always helps to show what you have written to this point, rather than have the rest of us try to visualize your code and improve it.

Comment: I've updated the code to hopefully make more sense of it. It is essentially trying to solve for three angles, when two are known and the third one is missing, but all three must add up to 180.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify which angle you're solving for; it's implicit in the problem's definition. If you start with something like this (anything resembling error handling elided):

```
class Triangle
  def initialize h
    h.keys.each { |key| instance_variable_set "@#{key}".to_sym, h[key] }
  end

  def to_s
    "a=#{@a}, b=#{@b}, c=#{@c}"
  end

  def solve
    angle = instance_variables.inject(180) { |v, a| v -= instance_variable_get(a) }
    [:@a, :@b, :@c].each {|s| instance_variable_set(s, angle) unless instance_variable_defined? s }
    self
  end
end
```

Then:

```
pry(main)> t = Triangle.new :a => 20, :c => 30
=> a=20, b=, c=30
pry(main)> t.solve
=> a=20, b=130, c=30
pry(main)>
```

You could also return/indicate which angle was actually solved for, if necessary.

This doesn't actually *avoid* an `if` statement, which was your specific question. It eliminates the need to explicitly spell each one of them out, which I took as the intent of the question.

If you truly need to "solve for", you could do add:

```
def solve_for sym
  solve
  instance_variable_get("@#{sym}".to_sym)
end
```

Technically, you could solve only after determining the value isn't set, but meh.

```
> t = Triangle.new :a => 20, :c => 30
=> a=20, b=, c=30
> t.solve_for :b
=> 130
> t
=> a=20, b=130, c=30
> t = Triangle.new :a => 20, :c => 30
=> a=20, b=, c=30
> t.solve_for :a
=> 20
> t
=> a=20, b=130, c=30
```

Comment: There are a few things in here that I don't quite understand how they work. Thanks for all this. I'll be playing around with it to make sure I understand how it works. I appreciate the time you put into this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just basic addition, multiplication, etc. then the following would suffice, but anything more complicated is not guaranteed.

```
def method(input)
  self.foo + self.bar + self.bad - input
end
```

Alternately, you could put them all in an array and delete the one you provided.

```
def method(input)
  [self.foo, self.bar, self.bad].reject { |e| e==input }.inject { ... }
end
```

Comment: Note that `delete` returns the deleted element (or `nil`), so the second snippet doesn't work.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Try somethng like this:

```
def method(arg)
  [ bar, bad, foo ].reject { |e| e == arg }.inject(:+)
end
```

Note that you don't to the `self` receiver, it's implicit.

Comment: I've added some clarification up above. I think I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
def solve_angles(missing)
      holder = [:A, :B, :C]
      holder.delete(missing)
      angle = 180 - (self.send(holder[0]) + self.send(holder[1]))
end
```

Is this a bad solution? Why?

Alternatively, is this any cleaner/better?

```
def solve_angles(missing)
  holder = [:A, :B, :C] - [missing]
  angle = 180 - send(holder[0]) - send(holder[1])
end
```

Or:

```
def solve_angles(missing)
  angles = [:A, :B, :C] - [missing]
  angles.inject(180) { |memo, a| memo - send(a) }
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it "bad", and if you have `attr_accessor`s on them all, seems like it'd work fine. Appending an edit to your answer.

Comment: One reason I tend towards more-generic solutions (rather than three sides explicitly) is that it lends itself to additional shapes, where it could be defined, filled, queried, etc. at runtime. For example, `s = Shape.new(sides: 5)` could do all the setup required to create a five-sided shape, including calculate the internal angle sum, create the angle accessors, etc.